# Mantener una sesion en varias aplicaciones

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, glassfish

Estoy utilizando java y jsf he creado algunas aplicaciones cada una con su propio login, ahora necesito validar sesión en una aplicaciones y al pasarme a otra aplicaciones no volver a iniciar sesión.

he probado guardado variables en sesión y creando cookies por cada aplicación, alguna sugerencia.

datos extras
 - Glasfish 4
 - primefaces
 - jsf

Comment: Sugiero un poco más de detalle en la pregunta, ¿Has intentado alguna forma para validarlos?

Answer (score 1):

Hola para replicar sesión entre tu ambiente puedas implementar el uso de Oracle Coherence, tendrás que ahcer algunas adecuaciones a tu archivo de despliegue y agregar el jar de coherence, adicional te dejo una liga con lso standard para compartir session entre aplicaciones.

En tu glassfish-web.xml

```
<glassfish-web-app> 
   <session-config> 
       <session-manager persistence-type="coherence-web" /> 
   </session-config> 
<glassfish-web-app>
```

[Session Sharing between Java Web Applications](http://www.eteration.com/session-sharing-between-java-web-applications/)

[Oracle Coherence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22620/glassfish.htm#COHCW360)

[Replicación de session WebLogic GlassFish Server](https://es.slideshare.net/phumphrey/http-session-replication-with-oracle-coherence-glassfish-weblogic)